A Possible Object Cycle was detected error
I get this error when i try to request this Controller
The errror message
JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.speciality.Doctor.Id.
The Controller
        public  IActionResult List(int id)
        {
            var doc = _context.Doctors.Include(t =>  t.speciality).ToList();
            return Json(doc);
        }

Here is the dataContext and models
    public class AppDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Speciality> Specialities { get; set; }

  
    }

    public class Doctor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int SpecialityId { get; set; }
        public Speciality speciality { get; set; }

    }

    public class Speciality
    {
        public int SpecialityId { get; set; }
        public string SpecialityName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Doctor> Doctor { get; set; }
    }

I tried using Async and await at first and it gave the same error
I installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson and still get this error

Doctor refers to a Specialty, which refers to (many) Doctor. You must break this cycle.

The root of the problem here is because you're using an Entity Framework entity type (class Doctor) as a JSON/web-service DTO, which means your JSON serializer is going to traverse all of your EF navigation-properties, potentially triggering lazy-loading to infinity - as well as getting stuck in reference-loops. For this reason (and many other reasons too) you should not use EF entity types as JSON DTOs. Instead, define your DTO types separately (yes, it's tedious) and have mapping methods (or use AutoMapper) to marshal between them.

Okay I will try this , thank you.

The problem you're facing is due to a circular reference between the Doctor and Speciality entities. When trying to convert this data to JSON, the serializer gets stuck in an infinite loop because each Doctor references a Speciality, which in turn references a Doctor, and so on.
To fix this, you can use the ReferenceHandler.Preserve option with `JsonSerializerOptions to handle reference loops. This approach will preserve object references and handle cycles during serialization.
Update your controller action to use JsonSerializer with ReferenceHandler.Preserve. Here is how you can modify your controller action:
public IActionResult List(int id)
{
    var doc = _context.Doctors.Include(t => t.speciality).ToList();
    
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
        WriteIndented = true
    };
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(doc, options);
    return Content(json, "application/json");
}

Also it is better to use the Json method provided by ASP.NET Core, you can configure the application-wide JSON options in Startup.cs as follows:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
            });

    // Other service configurations
}

Then, your original controller action can remain unchanged.
This approach configures the JSON serialization settings globally, so any JSON serialization in your application will use these settings by default.
